# c++ flood fill image recursive algorithm error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, flood-fill

I am writing a flood fill method to fill an image (an outline of a dog) with a red colour.

In my TestShellDlg.cpp is the flood fill method. CTestShellDlg::m_pScreenDib member is a CDIB32 bitmap class that contains the graphic and draws them.

I want to sample the current pixel and if it is not black (the colour of the outline) colour it red. This is the pre built getter in the Dib32.cpp class:

```
void CDIB32::GetRGB(int x, int y, BYTE& r, BYTE& g, BYTE& b)
{
    if (x >= Width() || y >= Height())
        IERROR;

    int off = y * ByteWid() + x * 4;
    b = m_pBits[off];
    g = m_pBits[off+1];
    r = m_pBits[off+2];
}
```

And here is my floodfill method in the TestShellDlg.cpp class:

```
void CTestShellDlg::FloodFill(CPoint& mid)
{
    byte r,g,b;
    //while the current pixel colour is not black, set it to red and recursively loop
    m_pScreenDib ->GetRGB(mid.x,mid.y, (byte) r,(byte) g,(byte)b);
        while(r !=(byte)0, g !=(byte)0, b !=(byte)0)
        {
            m_pScreenDib -> SetRGB(mid.x, mid.y,(byte)255,(byte) 0,(byte) 0);
            mid.x++;
            FloodFill(mid);
            mid.x--;
            FloodFill(mid);
            mid.y++;
            FloodFill(mid);
            mid.y--;
            FloodFill(mid);
        }

}
```

When building and running the project, I get a break point at the IERROR in the GetRGB() function.

Working through the stack, this happens at mid.x-- after several runs through. The program never seems to make it to mid.y++.

I have also tried this as my stopping condition:

```
while(mid.x < m_pScreenDib ->Width() && mid.y < m_pScreenDib -> Height())
```

with the same results.

Can anyone in the hive mind provide the reason and a possible solution? much gratitude to you all.

Comment: Stack overflow? Remember that a function call allocates memory on the stack, and the stack is limited. Do you *have* to use recursion?

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.No I do not have to use recursion. It was just my approach for ensuring every pixel was covered. I guess I will have to take a different tack. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems. Fix these first and see what happens:

1. You are calling `FloodFill` recursively while `r`, `g`, and `b` do not all equal 0. But you don't update any of these values in your while-loop. That would give you an endless loop.
2. Another problem is here:

   ```
       mid.x++;
       FloodFill(mid);
       mid.x--;
       FloodFill(mid);
   ```

   Let x be 100. After `mid.x++`, x will be 101. Then you do `x--` leaving you with x=100 again. So you are recursively calling `FloodFill()` with the same value of x. I don't think that's what you intended.
3. In `FloodFill`, you increment `x` before calling `FloodFill` again. But you don't check if you have reached the right border of the image, so `FloodFill` will be called recursively with ever greater values of `x` until you either get a stackoverflow, an access violation, or `x` is set to 0 agein because of integer overflow (whatever happens first).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that! On point 1 though, am I not changing the pixel value with this line:

`code m_pScreenDib -> SetRGB(mid.x, mid.y,(byte)255,(byte) 0,(byte) 0);`

Comment: @RyanRDizzleGraham Yes you change the pixel values, but not the *variables* `r`, `g` and `b`.

Comment: so also set them to r= 255, g =0, b=0 at the same time?

Comment: @RyanRDizzleGraham In which case you don't really need a loop.